# Bengali text analysis in R

Tags: r, algorithm, unicode, tm

I am working with Bengali text, have a data set which contains around 9800  tweets, Facebook status (Bengali text mixed with English) labeled with Positive negative sentiment.

I tried to perform Naïve Bayes algorithm for text classification and
    other machine learning algorithms.

I found challenges in

- Dealing with languages other than English (like Bengali)
- Cleaning data
- Creating document term matrix for Bengali text
- Inconsistent result (though it shows results)

So, using my data set (Bengali text) how I could perfectly perform Naïve Bayes Algorithm and other machine learning algorithms (decision tree, support vector machine)

NB:  i am sharing sample data 
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Al917DZ-85m3ghcLoFHX4rWUTFOS

```
library(tm)
library(e1071)
library(MLmetrics)
rawData <- bntextt
colnames(rawData) <- c("type", "text")
rawData$text <- iconv(rawData$text, to = "utf-8")
rawData$type <- factor(rawData$type)

sms_train_raw <- rawData[1:9800, ]$type
Sms_test_raw<- rawData[9801:9883,]$type
sms_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(rawData$text))

corpus <- tm_map(sms_corpus, content_transformer(tolower))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords())
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)

sms_corpus_train<-corpus[1:9800]
sms_corpus_test<-corpus[9801:9883]

sms_dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)

sms_dtm_train <- sms_dtm[1:9800,]
sms_dtm_test <- sms_dtm[9801:9883,]

five_times_words_train <- findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_train, 5)
five_times_words_test <- findFreqTerms(sms_dtm_test, 5)

sms_dtm_train <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_train,control=list(dictionary = five_times_words_train))
sms_dtm_test <- DocumentTermMatrix(sms_corpus_test,control=list(dictionary = five_times_words_test))

convert_count <- function(x) {
  y <- ifelse(x > 0, 1,0)
  y <- factor(y, levels=c(0,1), labels=c("No", "Yes"))
  y
}

sms_train <- apply(sms_dtm_train, 2, convert_count)
sms_test <- apply(sms_dtm_test, 2, convert_count)

sms_classifier <- naiveBayes(sms_train, sms_train_raw)
class(sms_classifier)
sms_test_pred <- predict(sms_classifier, newdata=sms_test,type="class")
table(Sms_test_raw,sms_test_pred)


Accuracy(sms_test_pred, testData$type)
F1_Score(sms_test_pred, testData$type)
```

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYQkS.png)
[Document term matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKLXk.png)

Comment: For someone who isn't familiar with the Bengali language, can you outline what the challenges are? Are the pos/neg markers not deducible from individual words, or does the orthography contain variations which obscures the identity relationship between different orthographical variations of what you perceive as "the same word"? Or do you not have enough data to form a strong signal for each of the words which carry a polarity?

Comment: Excel is a horrible format to share your data in, can you put it in something like CSV instead?

Comment: So what are your concrete problems?

Comment: The term matrix looks completely botched, are you sure the data is in UTF-8? If you remove some of the normalizations, do you get more terms? Lowercasing data which doesn't have case seems like a bad and potentially destructive idea, especially if the method doesn't know it's dealing with Unicode data (I'm not familiar with R so this is very speculative). Removing "punctuation" or "whitespace" could also remove some of your text if the method implementation is English/Latin-centric.

Comment: To be more specific, you would expect the term matrix to contain much more than 10 terms, and ideally, they should display as Bengali text, not some sort of [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake)

Comment: @triplee while i try to do Document Term Matrix using tm r package, then its now working, term its show in unknown format (not in unicode) and hard to undersatnd

Comment: As a rough workaround, can you replace the Bengali word tokens with just numbers?

Comment: @tripleee it would be a tough job to replace world tokens with Number

Comment: Ugly and clunky yes. Tough as in hard to do, not really. Mapping strings to numbers and back is not a hard problem, but if R doesn't understand your character set, you probably have to do this outside of R.  Or use a mapping which is easy to revert without a dictionary, like mapping the Unicode bytes to hex (আলহামদুলিল্লাহ maps to UTF-16 0986-09b2-09b9-09be-09ae-09a6-09c1-09b2-09bf-09b2-09cd-09b2-09be-09b9 where you probably have to strip the dashes from your "computer representation").

Comment: @DmitriySelivanov i also tried in text2vec r package for overall process to execute naive bayes but the results are confusing

Comment: Be wary of [Unicode normalization issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence), though. Probably make sure all your strings are NFC normal form.